# IQKeyboardManager Accessibility Issue

Tags: swift, accessibility, voiceover

I have been using IQKeyboardManager to control the keyboard in my app. I set the following attributes, and they work as expected.

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared().toolbarPreviousBarButtonItemAccessibilityLabel = "previous"
IQKeyboardManager.shared().toolbarNextBarButtonItemAccessibilityLabel = "next"
IQKeyboardManager.shared().toolbarDoneBarButtonItemAccessibilityLabel = "ok"
```

The problem is here: There is an empty button in the middle of the top toolbar. I think it is a suggestion or auto-correction field. I want to disable it for VoiceOver too. How can I do it?

I already opened an issue on GitHub. I'm not sure if this is an issue with the package or just me.

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/issues/1964

[image: screenshot]